# Issues with Laravel 8 storage folder under Windows 10 Apache virtual host

Tags: laravel, windows, apache, file-upload, storage

I triyng an image upload exercise from a tutorial found here

Here's the url of the tutorial
https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-8-image-upload-tutorial-exampleexample.html

And I have an issue with the storage. If I use the following method:

```
$request->image->storeAs('images', $imageName);
```

to store the image, it will not display in the preview, not even if I run
php artisan storage:link. Initially I got 404 error, but after long trials and errors I finally found that

```
<img src="{{ URL::asset('storage/images/'.Session::get('image')) }}">
```

is the only thing that got me closer, but I still get a 403 error.

On a virtual hosting only the public image folder would work. I can't use the store folder, much more private and secure. And this problem is driving me crazy.

I'm testing it using Apache on Windows 10 and I perfectly know that this issue is already addressed in another question here... but the solutions I found in that question only address the Linux operating system and they are not suitable to be tested locally under Windows.

Relative paths don't work with shortcuts in Windows and, since I would run a real life project under a shared hosting, I'm pretty sure that the problem have to do with some Apache directive that may be changed in .htaccess file, or, even better, with an ini_set function.

Thanks for any insight, all this puzzles me a lot!

Comment: did you link storage ? `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Sure I did it. But this is not the problem.

Comment: can you check where it got stored then? location

Comment: It get stored correctly. But if I use
<img src="{{ URL::asset('storage/images/'.Session::get('image')) }}">
I get a 403 error. Notice that this is a "unauthorized" error, it is not a "not found" error. 

The images are actually found, they are correctly stored, but I get a "not authorized" error when I try to display them.

Comment: `<img src="{{ Storage::url(Session::get('image')) }}">` use this to get url

Comment: If I use 

<img src="{{ Storage::url(Session::get('image')) }}">

it is the same thing. I still get 403 error. Unauthorized. 

As previously pointed, I think that it's probably a configuration problem in Apache. Maybe some directive in .htaccess or ini_set, would solve it. But, obviously, I'm not sure.

Comment: If I paste the url directly in the address bar 
http://fupload/storage/images/1609824427.jpg
I get 403 Forbidden
Apache/2.4.46 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1g PHP/7.4.10 Server at fupload Port 80

Comment: remove `fupload` from url or this may be you configure wrong server use `php artisan serve`

Comment: It seems that symbolic links don't work the same way in Windows than in Linux. It seems that Apache under Windows has troubles using Windows shortcuts. Could anyone, more experienced than I, confirm me that? Options FollowSymLinks (and all its variants) is completely ignored by Apache under Windows.